# HTML or Bootstrap image page

Tags: html, css, image

How to make a page like https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyseventeen/. (first page) 

full screen size bg image

fixed position image

covered by continued content

Comment: Have you looked at its page source?

Comment: have you even tried anything yourself?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
  <body style="background-image: url('http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-hrGFLyJba3U/Uh90QVFp01I/AAAAAAAAFoY/F5R7LBbTox0/s1600/Background-Picture-Html.jpg'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; ">
  
  <p style="color:#808080">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis maximus varius rutrum. Vivamus rutrum at nunc id pharetra. Cras consequat semper purus, ac rutrum mauris cursus eu. Nam vitae neque odio. Nunc eget justo quis magna pellentesque scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec consequat dui quis mollis laoreet. Nullam sit amet nisi eget nisi facilisis condimentum. Etiam in libero euismod, lobortis velit quis, convallis libero. Suspendisse lectus est, semper at dictum at, euismod sed turpis. Sed sapien purus, lacinia in mollis in, maximus et leo.</p>

<p style="color:#808080">Mauris purus libero, sagittis ac est at, porta lacinia nulla. Nullam scelerisque orci vitae ligula porta, ut egestas eros maximus. Sed fringilla nunc tortor, vel pretium magna convallis nec. Ut nec felis enim. Integer at est et arcu auctor blandit. Quisque faucibus urna nec augue faucibus, id iaculis justo ultrices. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla ornare, neque sit amet vestibulum venenatis, justo tortor tincidunt magna, ac vehicula urna nibh eu neque. Pellentesque volutpat nulla vestibulum imperdiet vestibulum.</p>

<p style="color:#808080">Praesent in arcu nisi. Integer sodales hendrerit nunc, non sodales ex. Sed sodales mattis venenatis. Proin ultricies sodales sem, non semper urna semper id. Proin fringilla vehicula cursus. Ut et sodales diam. Curabitur feugiat iaculis volutpat. Vestibulum rutrum hendrerit aliquet. Donec et massa quis ipsum sollicitudin pretium eu pellentesque felis.</p>

<p style="color:#808080">Maecenas pulvinar tristique urna non semper. Morbi porttitor, libero efficitur luctus dictum, nulla risus lobortis sapien, quis porttitor urna ipsum sit amet dolor. Pellentesque ac scelerisque mauris. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi maximus tellus scelerisque, rutrum quam sed, dignissim ipsum. Duis condimentum diam quis erat tempus, non eleifend felis tincidunt. Aenean laoreet turpis aliquam blandit commodo. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Duis sed efficitur tortor. Duis commodo, ligula sed egestas ultrices, purus quam suscipit nulla, ac cursus nunc libero et orci. Nulla quam est, condimentum volutpat libero id, fringilla finibus enim. Pellentesque maximus rhoncus sapien. Curabitur in placerat nunc. Nullam varius, neque quis fringilla luctus, metus tellus posuere dui, sed rutrum nunc sem tempus odio. Quisque efficitur posuere sollicitudin.</p>

<p style="color:#808080">Maecenas nec sodales erat, sit amet tempus orci. Suspendisse sit amet eros quis nulla mollis lobortis at ut metus. Phasellus faucibus ullamcorper elit, ac congue nulla faucibus vel. Aenean hendrerit felis quis nisi dignissim lobortis. Nunc consequat erat ac nibh hendrerit vehicula. Quisque efficitur fringilla risus in tincidunt. Maecenas eu tempor ante. Mauris vitae volutpat metus. Nulla aliquet orci et elit vehicula, eu cursus libero pharetra. Aliquam nec tortor vel nibh tincidunt sagittis. Curabitur aliquet ex turpis.</p>
  
  </body>
```

```
background-image: url('path/to/picture.jpg'); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
```